# filter on data which are numeric

Tags: scala, apache-spark

hi i have  a dataframe with a column CODEARTICLE here is the dataframe

```
|CODEARTICLE|    STRUCTURE|                 DES|TYPEMARK|TYP|IMPLOC|MARQUE|GAMME|TAR|
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---+------+------+-----+---+
| GENCFFRIST|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  0| Local|      |     |   |
| GENCFFMARC|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  0| Local|      |     |   |
| GENCFFESCO|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  0| Local|      |     |   |
|  GENCFFTNA|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  0| Local|      |     |   |
| GENCFFEMBA|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  0| Local|      |     |   |
|  789600010|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       7|  1| Local|      |     |   |
|  799700040|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  1| Local|      |     |   |
|  799701000|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  1| Local|      |     |   |
|  899980490|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  9| Local|      |     |   |
|  429600010|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  1| Local|      |     |   |
|  559970040|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  0| Local|      |     |   |
|  679500010|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  1| Local|      |     |   |
|  679500040|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  1| Local|      |     |   |
|  679500060|9999999999998|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...|       0|  1| Local|      |     |   |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---+------+------+-----+---+
```

i would like to take only rows having a numeric CODEARTICLER
  //connect to table TMP_STRUCTURE oracle

```
  val spark = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val articles_Gold = spark.load("jdbc",
    Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:System/maher@//localhost:1521/XE",
      "dbtable" -> "IPTECH.TMP_ARTICLE")).select("CODEARTICLE", "STRUCTURE", "DES", "TYPEMARK", "TYP", "IMPLOC", "MARQUE", "GAMME", "TAR")

val filteredData =articles_Gold.withColumn("test",'CODEARTICLE.cast(IntegerType)).filter($"test"!==null)
```

thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `na.drop`:

```
articles_Gold.withColumn("test",'CODEARTICLE.cast(IntegerType)).na.drop("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.isNotNull` function on the column in your `filter` function. You don't even need to create another column for your logic. You can simply do the following

```
val filteredData = articles_Gold.withColumn("CODEARTICLE",'CODEARTICLE.cast(IntegerType)).filter('CODEARTICLE.isNotNull)
```

I hope the answer is helpful